# Using KDDockWidgets in PySide2 with QML

Tags: python, qt, cmake, qml, pyside2

I am trying to get [KDDockWidgets 2.0](https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets/tree/2.0) into my PySide2 Python 3.10 application. I have followed the [Python bindings guide](https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets/blob/2.0/README-bindings.md) they provide (with great confusion on a Windows machine) and now am able to build KDDockWidgets with CMake, however, it is absolutely unclear what I do from here to actually be able to use the bindings in my QML code. I see in one of their [examples](https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets/blob/2.0/examples/qtquick/dockwidgets/main.qml) what would be imported in QML, but how would PySide2 know where to look for it?

The guide gives me the impression that it would generate a Python module in my virtual environment's site-packages, but there is no evidence of it doing that, nor do I see any errors at all.

My build script:

```
setlocal
set VS_YEAR="2022"
set KDDW_REPO="KDDW"
set PY_ENV_NAME="env"
set PY_SITE_PKG="F:\Projects\Code\Python\boslin\env\Lib\site-packages\"
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\%VS_YEAR%\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cd %KDDW_REPO%
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDDockWidgets_PYTHON_BINDINGS=True -DKDDockWidgets_PYTHON_BINDINGS_INSTALL_PREFIX=%PY_SITE_PKG%
endlocal
```